# Selenium WebElement Extend - Add property Parent FRAME

Tags: java, selenium

Has anybody ever tried to extend Selenium WebElement?
I want to add a property to the WebElement called parent Frame and if the value is set, then first switch to the frame before executing any actions.
This should allow for a frame to have a frame parent as well.

Comment: Selenium can't detect that element without switching to the frame first... you might be able to write a method that iterates through frames, though.

Comment: I was hoping to extend a class or implement a method that maps a webelement to a parent element. So I am leaning to wrapping the driver and provide some mapping between element and parent, so when the element needs interaction, the driver should first switch. I am however trying not to extend too much from selenium

Comment: right, the problem is you need to switch the driver to detect the element.